# Moving placeholder text in Autocomplete component in React

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, uisearchbar

I'm trying to create a Material UI's [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component. Instead of showing suggestions of Autocomplete as dropdown, How can I show it as moving placeholder? The text inside the Autocomplete component should slide in left?

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-mgg7z?file=/demo.js

The search results (The Godfather) should have a slide in left motion as a placeholder.

Comment: Are you looking for behaviour similar to what we have in Gmail (autocomplete text while typing emails) or in MSExcel (where if the same text comes in grey colour)?

Comment: I want a moving placeholder inside the text box. The moving placeholder should be search suggestions. For instance, if I have a search text box [to search list of countries], then user should be able to see country list inside the textbox as animated placeholder moving right to left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom hook useAnimatedPlaceholder in this demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2em32?file=/demo.js

It can be easily inserted into any input base components. The functionality is achieved via using the useEffect and setTimeout combo. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If the textfield is empty, then there should be a moving placeholder. So for your example, the textfield should show 'The God, The Shawshank Redemption' moving right to left [placeholder] inside the textbox

Comment: A animated placeholder that flow from right to left? Sound like a bad ux idea if it was inside the textfield because it will mess the user input. What about underneath the textfield as a helper text?

Comment: How about the implementation of search bar on this website: https://www.covid19india.org/ ?

Comment: Indeed, that example make a lot more sense. I’ll modify my answer when I have time

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a text field inside autocomplete.

Comment: Should I send it as a prop?